# Instalé Android Studio pero sale "Error:Failed to complete Gradle execution"

Tags: android-studio, gradle, java

Luego de instalar Android Studio, muestra:

> Error:Failed to complete Gradle execution.
>
> Cause: Process 'command '/usr/local/android-studio/jre/bin/java''
>   finished with non-zero
>   exit value 126

Instalé nuevamente el jdk 1.8.101 y jre pero sigue saliendo el mismo error.

Comment: Asegúrate de que se han instalado las dos carpetas en tu sistema. Tanto jdk como jre.

Answer (score 1):

> Error:Failed to complete Gradle execution.
>
> Cause: Process 'command '/usr/local/android-studio/jre/bin/java''
>   finished with non-zero exit value
>   126

Asegura instalar la versión de java y Android Studio adecuada para tu sistema operativo.

Si tu sistema operativo es de 64bits o 32 bits, asegura instalar la version correspondiente.

Answer (score 0):

Aunque esta respuesta llega tarde, por si a alguien le sigue siendo de ayuda, puede que al descomprimir android-studio fallen los permisos de ejecucion de varios programas necesarios para android-studio. Prueba a ejecutar lo siguiente desde la carpeta donde tienes instalado android studio:

```
for f in `find . -name bin`; do chmod +x $f/*; done
```

En tu caso, al estar en /usr/local puede ejecutar directamente desde cualquier sitio:

```
for f in `find /usr/local/android-studio -name bin`; do sudo chmod +x $f/*; done
```